# Trouble accessing numpy array defined in class

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, oop, tkinter

I'm coming to python from C (so not a ton of OOP experience) and I'm stuck working on a tkinter project when trying to create an array within a class that I can access from another class. Here's a MWE:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import tkinter.font as font
import numpy as np

class Table():
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initArray()
    
    def initArray(self):
        cells = np.zeros((2,2))
        self.cells = cells
        self.rows_len = len(self.cells)
        self.columns_len = len(self.cells[0])


class MatFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        rows = len(Table.cells)
        columns = len(Table.cells[0])
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Matrix GUI")
        self.table = Table()
        self.mat_frame = MatFrame(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('1000x600')
    App(root)
    root.resizable(0,0)
    root.mainloop()
```

When running this, I recieve

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/dev/Python/mwe.py", line 44, in <module>
    App(root)
  File "/home/username/dev/Python/mwe.py", line 35, in __init__
    self.initUI()
  File "/home/username/dev/Python/mwe.py", line 39, in initUI
    self.mat_frame = MatFrame(self)
  File "/home/username/dev/Python/mwe.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.initUI()
  File "/home/username/dev/Python/mwe.py", line 25, in initUI
    rows = len(Table.cells)
AttributeError: type object 'Table' has no attribute 'cells'
```

I'm not sure why I am getting this error as I believe I have initialized Table.cells properly. Any ideas why I am getting this error? Thanks!

Comment: The code fails at rows = len(Table.cells), you are using "Tables" the class and not a object that inherits from that class

Comment: You never assign to `Table.cells` at all, you create *instance* variables, for *instances of the `Table` class*.

Comment: Thank you both. After doing some more reading, I solved it by having initArray return a value and getting my value from that. Thanks again!